# How do I ensure the hidden WIFI network is remembered on ChromeOS Flex after rebooting?

Tags: google-chrome-os, google-chrome-os-flex

Using [ChromeOS Flex](https://support.google.com/chromeosflex/answer/11552529?hl=en) on an older Toshiba laptop.

Every time I power down/reboot and login, the hidden WIFI network is not reconnecting, and it is not in the list of WIFI networks to choose from (other networks are).

I have to manually add my network every time.

How do I ensure the hidden WIFI network is remembered on ChromeOS Flex?

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to unhide it? It's poor practise anyway.

Comment: Why is it poor practice to hide it, @Tetsujin? Every other OS can connect to it automatically while hidden.

Comment: It's less secure than having a name - see https://www.howtogeek.com/780747/stop-hiding-your-wi-fi-network/ for a simple explanation.

Comment: Thanks, @Tetsujin, that was good; my SSIDs are now unhidden. On that URL is: `"Use a strong, modern Wi-Fi encryption method such as WPA2-Personal"`. My router uses `WPA2 Personal`, but the version of `WPA2 Personal` is `WPA2-PSK`. Is this fine? Add an answer if you like.

Comment: PSK [pre-shared key] is part of WPA Personal. Plenty good enough for home use. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Protected_Access [I don't have the expertise to really get this down in an answer, it's all second-hand knowledge I've picked up over the years from various articles like the one I linked before.]